# No Python on Fedora 29 Copr

Tags: fedora, rpmbuild

One of my src `rpm`s submitted to [Copr](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/) for build failed because there is no Python implementation; is this because something is wrong with the src rpm itself, or there is simply no Python implementation on copr machines, or did I miss some settings?

```
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for python... no
BUILDSTDERR: configure: error: You need 'python' to compile XXX
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's very likely that you are missing one or more of:

```
BuildRequires: python2-devel

BuildRequires: python3-devel

BuildRequires: python-unversioned-command
```

in your spec file. The build environment starts out rather minimal and BuildRequires are used to pull in additional things. Python is rather large, so there was effort to move it from the default buildroot a little while ago.

See [Dependencies](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Python/#_dependencies) in the Python section of the Fedora Packaging Guidelines.

If your program refers to `/usr/bin/python` without a version number, you'll need `python-unversion-command`. See [this Fedora change](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Move_usr_bin_python_into_separate_package) for detail on that — in short, upstream Python has decided that `/usr/bin/python` can refer to *either* version depending on what the user wants, which means that operating system packages should really use either `python2` or `python3` explicitly. Requiring the unversioned command is an option for when you don't want to patch your program to do that for whatever reason.

Comment: hello, i added that line in spec, but configure still fails; same error (no python); it's the [webkitgtk](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/26/Everything/source/tree/Packages/w/webkitgtk-2.4.11-5.fc26.src.rpm) source rpm pulled from fedora 26 (because it was removed since fedora 27);

Comment: Possible that that requires Python 2?

Comment: it seems on fedora 29 `/usr/bin/python` is installed by package `python-unversioned-command`, neither `python2` nor `python3`; does this matter? [source](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Move_usr_bin_python_into_separate_package)

Comment: looks like problem goes away when i added `BuildRequires: python-unversioned-command` in addition to the other two `BuildRequires`; now it passed configure and started make; thank you very much;